# How do I SSH into github codespace provided by CS50

Tags: linux, github, ssh, cs50

I have a codespace provided by CS50. I want to ssh into it using my local terminal. I installed github-cli.
When I run `gh cs list` It shows the codespace :

```
NAME                                                     DISPLAY NAME            REPOSITORY       BRANCH  STATE      CREATED AT
roshanpaudel111-literate-space-sniffle-g6x64ww79x9cvgg9  literate space sniffle  code50/65642985  main    Available  6d
```

But when I try to ssh into it using this command `gh cs ssh roshanpaudel111-literate-space-sniffle-g6x64ww79x9cvgg9`, it shows the following output:

```
? Choose codespace: code50/65642985 (main): literate space sniffle
ubuntu@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
shell closed: exit status 255
```

How can I solve this issue?
The whole process looks like this :

```
linux@linux ~ $ gh cs list
NAME                                                     DISPLAY NAME            REPOSITORY       BRANCH  STATE      CREATED AT
roshanpaudel111-literate-space-sniffle-g6x64ww79x9cvgg9  literate space sniffle  code50/65642985  main    Available  6d
linux@linux ~ $ gh cs ssh roshanpaudel111-literate-space-sniffle-g6x64ww79x9cvgg9
? Choose codespace: code50/65642985 (main): literate space sniffle

ubuntu@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
shell closed: exit status 255
linux@linux ~ [1] $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the format of the private key you registered in  [GitHub Codespaces](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/developing-in-codespaces/using-github-codespaces-with-github-cli#ssh-into-a-codespace).

It should start with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` and ends with `-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` (meaning a non-encrypted private key)
The EOL (end of lines) used in that file should be LF (not the Windows CRLF), although if you copy-pasted its content directly, it should be fine.

See also the process followed in [`cs50/codespace` issue 62](https://github.com/cs50/codespace/issues/62#issuecomment-1208477067).

---

The [OP Rosan Paudel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15894598/rosan-paudel) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056717/how-do-i-ssh-into-github-codespace-provided-by-cs50/75066747?noredirect=1#comment132471358_75066747):

> I think it works with the codespaces that we create manually.
> I was trying to ssh into a codespace that is provided by cs50 which is in my repository.
> Whenever I run `update50` it screws up everything. So I have to backoff doing any tweaks.

Comment: Thank you @VonC I tried this, I think it works with the codespaces that we create manually. I was trying to ssh into a codespace that is provided by cs50 which is in my repo. Whenever I run `update50` it scews up everything. So I have to backoff doing any tweaks.